# Multiple if conditions, without nesting

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

I have a sample piece of code below that I need some help on. The code sets the 'outcome' variable to False in the beginning and only should become True if all the 'if' conditions are met. Is there a more efficient way of doing this? I am trying to avoid nested 'if' statements.

Thanks!

```
    outcome = False

    while True:
        if a != b:
            print("Error - 01")
            break

        if a["test_1"] != "test_value":
            print("Error - 02")
            break

        if "test_2" not in a:
            print("Error - 03")
            break

        if a["test_3"] == "is long data string":
            print("Error - 04")
            break

        outcome = True
        break
```

Comment: I think readability counts here more than performance, but I could be wrong. [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533338/python-efficiency-of-and-vs-multiple-ifs)

Comment: `if statement and statement and statement :` did you try this?

Comment: I could use 'and' but would need specific error codes for each condition. :(

Comment: @RaymondC. [This is probably related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539116/python-if-statement-efficiency)

Comment: why is all of that in a `while` loop? neither `a` nor `b` change...

Comment: You can start by removing the while loop. Also this should probably be on codereview

Comment: you can use some counter to check all the if statement is true like `if True: count+=1 if count==4 : output = True` something like this

Comment: So the reason why I am using a while loop is that if condition 1 fails it would not move on because there may be exceptions if I let the checks continue. Sorry I did not mention this earlier.

Comment: The counter method seems like a good idea.

Comment: It is not yet 8 AM here so I may be still asleep, but isn't an if...elif...elif...else chain the obvious way to write this?

Comment: Yes is it marked as the solution given below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write it like this, so the function ends once it encounters an error, and the most likely error should be on top, and if it encounters that error, it will return False and end the function. Else, it will check for all the other errors and then eventually conclude that the outcome is indeed True.

```py
# testOutcome returns a boolean
outcome = testOutcome(a,b)

# Expects a and b
# Breaks out of the function call once error happens
def testOutcome(a,b):
    # Most likely error goes here
    if a != b:
        print("Error - 01")
        return False

    # Followed by second most likely error
    elif a["test_1"] != "test_value":
         print("Error - 02")
         return False

    # Followed by third most likely error
    elif "test_2" not in a:
         print("Error - 03")
         return False

    # Least likely Error
    elif a["test_3"] == "is long data string":
         print("Error - 04")
         return False

    else:
        return True
```

Comment: Interesting, I did not think of it this way. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Or another way :

```
    outcome = True

    if a != b:
        print("Error - 01")
        outcome &= False

    if a["test_1"] != "test_value":
        print("Error - 02")
        outcome &= False

    if "test_2" not in a:
        print("Error - 03")
        outcome &= False

    if a["test_3"] == "is long data string":
        print("Error - 04")
        outcome &= False
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. Just wanted to say thanks :)
Question: Why do you use &=  instead of = ?

Comment: Oh, I made it complicated, you can use `=` instead. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hackiest way of doing this as per user request, not recommended tho,
There are many ways to use structures if you are only looking to understand them.
Functions like zip or list comprehension can be used once you convert to list
Used list to keep positions intact.

```
a = {'test_1' : "test_value", 'test_4' : "None", 'test_3' : "long data string"}
b = {'test_1' : "test_value", 'test_4' : "None", 'test_3' : "long data string"}

# storing bool values, expecting True
test1 =  [a==b,"test_2" in a,a["test_1"] == "test_value", a["test_3"] != "is long data string" ]

# storing error codes for False conditions 
result = ["Error - 01", "Error - 02", "Error - 03", "Error - 04"]

if False in test1:
    print(result[int(test1.index(False))])
else:
    print(True)
```

```
Error - 02

[Program finished]
```